# The coordinates of the range are outside the dimensions of the sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Hi I'm pretty new to Google Scripts and I'm coming up with this problem. When running the script it comes up with the error `The coordinates of the range are outside the dimensions of the sheet`.

I'm wanting to copy the data from "Property No Heading" to "Property Script". The data must be appended to the bottom of the table on "Property Script". Can anyone help me out?

```
 function moveData() {/**
 * @OnlyCurrentDoc
 */
  // Get handles to Daily and Archive sheets
  var dailySheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Property No Heading');
  var appendSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Property Script');

  // Create range strings for the rows in Daily and Archive sheets
  var dailySheetRange = "Property No Heading!2:" + dailySheet.getLastRow();
  var archiveLastRow = dailySheet.getLastRow() + appendSheet.getLastRow();
  var archiveAppendRange = "Property Script!" + (appendSheet.getLastRow() + 1) + ":" + archiveLastRow;

  // Get range of data to copy
  var destRange = dailySheet.getRange(archiveAppendRange);

  // Copy the data to the archive sheet
  var sourceDataValues = dailySheet.getRange(dailySheetRange).copyTo(destRange,{contentsOnly:true});
```

Comment: Hi! Did my answer work for you ?

Comment: Hi, yes it did - thanks so much! Sorry I'm new to Stack and didn't know how to reply!

Answer (score 0):

### Issues / Explanation:

- As [Diego](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1329498/diego) mentioned in his comments, [copyTo()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copytodestination) will not automatically change the dimensions of the target sheet.
- It is recommended to use [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues) / [setValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues) in this scenario and copy based on the [length](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length) of the input array.
- The following script will copy and paste the full data of `Property No Heading` after the last row with content of the `Property Script` sheet.

If you want to copy only the **first** column then replace:

`const dShData = dSh.getRange(2,1,dSh.getLastRow()-1,dSh.getLastColumn()).getValues();`

with:

`const dShData = dSh.getRange(2,1,dSh.getLastRow()-1).getValues();`

to get only the first column.

---

### Solution:

```
 function moveData() {
   
   const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
   const dSh = ss.getSheetByName('Property No Heading');
   const aSh = ss.getSheetByName('Property Script');
   const dShData = dSh.getRange(2,1,dSh.getLastRow()-1,dSh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
   aSh.getRange(aSh.getLastRow()+1,1,dShData.length,dShData[0].length).setValues(dShData);
 }
```

Comment: The issue here is that `copyTo()` will not automatically change the dimensions of the target sheet, unlike other similar methods.

Comment: does it accept google sheet notation like: `Sheet1!A1:A` ?  @Diego

Comment: Yessir, it does!

Comment: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangea1notation

Comment: Oops, thanks a lot. I didn't know that. I will update my answer. @Diego

Comment: @Diego I mean, I knew about notations like `A1:A` but I didn't know you could specify the sheet name also.

Comment: It makes sense if you use `getRange()` on the spreadsheet itself. Specifying it when calling from the sheet is either redundant or evil, since `sheet1.getRange('Sheet2!A1')` will actually return the value from sheet2 

Comment: @Diego thanks for the info :) I didn't know it. I always like to specify sheet objects and I didn't come across with this approach.